# ComboBox e ligação à base de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Boa tarde!
Estou a ter alguma dificuldades em submeter os dados da combobox na listview devido a um erro que aparece e que nao consigo resolver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro que me dá é este

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este aqui é o código onde o erro é apontado(seta preta)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou adicionando outra resposta para não poluir muito a minha atual solução que seria o mais correto.

A sua saída é criar uma classe que vou chamar de `ComboBoxItem` e adicionar os valores utilizando ela, ao invés de adicionar pelas Propriedades.

```
Class ComboBoxItem

    Public Property Text As String ' sua descrição
    Public Property Value As Integer ' seu código

    Sub New(ByVal text As String, value As Integer)
        Me.Text = text
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Text
    End Function
End Class
```

E no seu CodeBehind você vai popular o `combobox`dessa forma:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim computadores As List(Of ComboBoxItem) = New List(Of ComboBoxItem)

    computadores.Add(New ComboBoxItem("D11", 1))
    computadores.Add(New ComboBoxItem("D12", 2))
    computadores.Add(New ComboBoxItem("D13", 3))

    pcTB.DataSource = computadores
End Sub
```

E para recuperar o valor é só fazer parecido com minha outra solução:

```
.Add("@codComp", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CType(pcTB.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Com base nos comentários acredito que seu problema não seja na estrutura e sim no modo que você está recuperando o valor do `combobox`, você apenas possui a `descrição` no `combobox` e não o identificador `id`.

Eu perguntei sobre como você está populando o `pcTB` pra te dar uma solução mais exata, se você está apenas preenchendo com a descrição ou está passando o objeto do tipo `Computador`.

### Solução usando o model `Computador`

Na hora que você carregar seus dados no `combobox`.

```
' Verifica o nome correto aqui utilizei `Form1`
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'seu código se ja tiver

    ' caso você não tenha esse if ainda, é bom ter
    ' ele verifica se foi um PostBack, exemplo se clicou no botão é PostBack
    ' se você acabou de carregar o Form então NÃO é PostBack
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        CarregaComputadores()
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub CarregaComputadores() 
    ' aqui você prepara a conexão com seu banco
    Dim objconnect2 As SqlConnection = 'sua conexão
    Dim command As SqlCommand

    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim sql As String = "select codComp, descricaoComp FROM Computadores"

    Try
        connection.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, objconnect2)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        adapter.Dispose()
        command.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
        pcTB.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        'Especificar qual coluna exibe e qual valor retorna
        pcTB.DisplayMember = "descricaoComp" 'Campo que exibe para usuário
        pcTB.ValueMember = "codComp" 'Valor para esse texto
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Erro ao carregar os computadores! ")
    End Try
End Sub
```

E depois para recuperar esses valores você faz assim

```
.Add("@codComp", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ctype(pcTB.SelectedItem, Computador).codComp
```

Preste atenção ao `SqlDbType.Int` e ao `CAST` para recuperar o valor.

Comment: dá erro no " as ", aparece ')' expected

Comment: @Forrobodo Vacilo meu, usei o cast do `C#`, atualizei agora corretamente no `vb.net` :)

Comment: @Forrobodo Poste o código de como você coloca valores no `pcTB`, como você está atribuindo valor a ele? Desse jeito consigo ajeitar a resposta